How to pass tkimage raw data to cv2 functions?
TLDR
I am writing a video recorder with tkinter and cv2. How to pass tkimage raw data to cv2.VideoWriter, cv2.circle, and so on?
Current approach
I using a numpy array (self.data) as a middle man. But this way I need to create a new tkimage each time. So, after creating it once, I want to access tkimage data directly with cv2 functions. The following class encapsulates tkimage and the numpy array:
import cv2
import numpy as np
// import tkinter as tk
// from tkinter import Canvas
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Bitmap:
    def __init__(self, size=(512, 512)):
        self.data = np.zeros((size[1], size[0], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        self._image_id = 0
        self._image = None

    @property
    def size(self):
        return (self.data.shape[1], self.data.shape[0])

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self.data.shape[1]

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self.data.shape[0]

    @property
    def clear(self):
        self.data.fill(0)

    def new_image(self):
        self._image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(self.data))
        return self._image_id, self._image

    @property
    def image(self):
        return self._image_id, self._image

    def setup(self, canvas):
        self._image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(self.data))
        self._image_id = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=self._image)

Write to self.data:
cv2.circle(self.bitmap.data, (x, y), 5, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

Write to video file:
// self.recorder = cv2.VideoWriter()
self.recorder.write(self.bitmap.data)

Use self.image to update tkinter ui:
// self._image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(self.data))
id, image = self.bitmap.image
self.canvas.itemconfig(id, image=image)

So, how to write direcly to tkinter.image data?

I might be wrong, but from the looks of it you can only put data into a tkinter PhotoImage by encoding it as an image file (which Pillow must be doing internally). And so it also is impossible to get that data back out again. Tkinter is easy to use, but not the best way to make complex GUIs. Maybe try Qt?

even worse than that, the image data is transferred to Tk, where it is no longer in a Python context, and you cannot access that in any direct way. that's why it is impossible to use Tk for any "fast" image/video display. all you can do is (repeatedly) pack your data into a PhotoImage and send that to Tk to display, but you'll never get that back.

Although I am not able to give a proper answer for my tkinter question, I feel that for my (GPL3 friendly) use case, the Qt suggestion given by Cris was excellent (see https://doc.qt.io/Qt-6/qimage.html#constBits for more details). So, while there is no known (simpler) solution for tkinter, this answer may hopefully help someone that need stuff done (tested on Python 3.11.2, Qt 6.6.0 and OpenCV 4.8.0).
The Bitmap class encapsulates image data for both cv2 access (self.data) and display optimized Qt access (self.pixmap).
from PySide6.QtGui import (
    QImage,
    QPixmap,
)

import cv2
import numpy as np

class Bitmap:
    def __init__(self, width, height, channels=3):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.channels = channels
        self.data = np.zeros((self.height, self.width, self.channels), dtype=np.uint8)
        self.pixmap = self.pixmap_from_data()

    @property
    def invalidate(self):
        self.pixmap = self.pixmap_from_data()

    @property
    def clear(self):
        self.data.fill(0)

    def data_from_pixmap(self):
        return np.frombuffer(
            self.pixmap.toImage().constBits(),
            dtype = np.uint8).reshape((self.height, self.width, self.channels))

    def data_from_pixmap_RGBA(self):
        return cv2.cvtColor(np.frombuffer(
            self.pixmap.toImage().constBits(),
            dtype = np.uint8).reshape((self.height, self.width, self.channels)),
            cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)

    def pixmap_from_data(self):
        return QPixmap.fromImage(
            QImage(
                self.data,
                self.width,
                self.height,
                self.width * self.channels,
                QImage.Format_BGR888))

You can override the paintEvent method of QWidget and use QPainter to render stuff for display:
from PySide6.QtCore import (
    QPoint
)

from PySide6.QtGui import (
    QPainter
)

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget
)

class RenderArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=800, height=600):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.bitmap = Bitmap(width = width, height = height)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(self.width, self.height)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        canvas = QPainter(self)

        for child in self.components:
            child.paint(self.bitmap.data)
        self.bitmap.invalidate

        canvas.drawPixmap(QPoint(0, 0), self.bitmap.pixmap)
        canvas.end()

You can use the RenderArea class inside a QWidget container and you can run it using QApplication:
from PySide6.QtCore import (
    Qt
)

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QWidget
)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._render_area = RenderArea()

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self._render_area, 0, 0, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

